# How to use python multiprocessing module in django view

Tags: python, django, multiprocessing

I have a simple function that go over a list of URLs, using `GET` to retrieve some information and update the DB (`PostgresSQL`) accordingly. The function works perfect. However, going over each URL one at a time talking too much time.

Using python, I'm able to do to following to parallel these tasks:

```
from multiprocessing import Pool

def updateDB(ip):
     code goes here...

if __name__ == '__main__':
    pool = Pool(processes=4)              # process per core
    pool.map(updateDB, ip)
```

This is working pretty well. However, I'm trying to find how do the same on django project. Currently I have a function (view) that go over each URL to get the information, and update the DB.

The only thing I could find is using Celery, but this seems to be a bit overpower for the simple task I want to perform.

Is there anything simple that i can do or do I have to use Celery?

Comment: Is this a reoccurring task? Maybe a custom management command run as a cronjob is an alternative.

Comment: It really depends on the response time you want. You could have your server respond immediately after spwaning Celery tasks, or you can do multiprocessing and then it will still take some time. Don't bother with `multiprocessing` though, I suggest using the excellent `joblib` library.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> Currently I have a function (view) that go over each URL to get the
>   information, and update the DB.

It means response time does not matter for you and instead of doing it in the background (asynchronously), you are OK with doing it in the foreground if your response time is cut by 4 (using 4 sub-processes/threads). If that is the case you can simply put your sample code in your view. Like

```
from multiprocessing import Pool

def updateDB(ip):
     code goes here...

def my_view(request):
    pool = Pool(processes=4)              # process per core
    pool.map(updateDB, ip)
    return HttpResponse("SUCCESS")
```

But, if you want to do it asynchronously in the background then you should use Celery or follow one of @BasicWolf's suggestions.

Comment: That's exactly my case. I don't need anything to run on the background (that's why I find Celery not to be the best solution). 

I actually tried your suggestion since I assumed it might works. However, I got an error "Models aren't loaded yet." and though this is just not possible.

Do you have any idea why the following exception appears?
Exception Type: AppRegistryNotReady
Exception Value: Models aren't loaded yet.

Comment: What is your Django vesion? working for me on Django 1.8.2

Comment: Django version 1.8.6

I'll go over my code again to make sure I did all changes correctly. I think I would try this with a new simple function. Maybe something else in my code making troubles.

Comment: It basically works. My exception been through when somewhere in "updateDB" function, I'm adding class to class (ManyToMany relation): cluster.clusterRpas.add(rpa). Than for some reason, the exception "Models aren't loaded yet" comes.

Comment: What do you think if it might be a solution to create a microservice (like FastAPI) with great async support and use it for asynchronously call Django API, which will do the task for the one use case?

Answer (score 7):

Though using Celery may seem an overkill, it is a well-known way of doing asynchronous tasks. Essentially Django serves WSGI request-response cycle which knows nothing of multiprocessing or background tasks.

Here are alternative options:

- [Django background tasks](https://github.com/arteria/django-background-tasks) - might fit your case better.
- [Redis queue](http://python-rq.org/)

Comment: I'm curious why you think Celery is overkill? It seems the Go To solution for production sites that rely on farming work out and keeping a web page updated on progress. Perhaps it's hard to install and get running? Certainly seems a bit involved, where Redis queue pitches itself with a low entry barrier.

Comment: It really depends on a case. If an infrastructure is limited to "Django + Python only" and there is no way to use a message broker like RabbitMQ then one would be having hard times. But sure, for something more serious than a small hobby project, I'd go with Celery.

Comment: Using celery is it possible to wait until all functions calls will be executed?
Like `asyncio.gather`

Answer (score 1):

I will recommend to use [gevent](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/gevent) for multithreading solution instead of multiprocessing. Multiprocessing can cause problem in production environment where spawning new processes are restricted.

Example code:

```
from django.shortcuts import HttpResponse
from gevent.pool import Pool

def square(number):
    return number * number

def home(request):
    pool = Pool(50)
    numbers = [1, 3, 5]
    results = pool.map(square, numbers)
    return HttpResponse(results)
```

Comment: Gevent is for I/O bound tasks that are coroutine aware.  Totally the incorrect tool for this task.