# Process Several Pcap Files Simultaneously - Django

Tags: django, multithreading, python-3.x, scapy, pcap

In essence, the following function, called by the user of the django application that I am developing, uses the Scapy library to process 80-odd fairly large pcaps in order to initially parse their destination IP addresses.

I was wondering whether it would be possible to process several pcaps simultaneously, as the CPU is not being utilised to it's full capacity, ideally using multi-threading

```
def analyseall(request):
    allpcaps = Pcaps.objects.all()
    for individualpcap in allpcaps:
        strfilename = str(individualpcap.filename)
        print(strfilename)
        pcapuuid = individualpcap.uuid
        print(pcapuuid)
        packets = rdpcap(strfilename)
        print("hokay")
        for packet in packets:
            if packet.haslayer(IP):
    #            print(packet[IP].src)

     #       print(packet[IP].dst)
                dstofpacket = packet[IP].dst

                PcapsIps.objects.update_or_create(ip=dstofpacket, uuid=individualpcap)

    return render(request, 'about.html', {"list": list})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use above answer (multiprocessing), and also improve scapy’s reading speed, by using the PcapReader generator rather than rdpcap

```
with PcapReader(filename) as fdesc:
    for pkt in fdesc:
        [actions on the pkt]
```

Comment: I've been using scapy's inbuilt 'sniff' functionality now, is that faster or slower than pcapreader?

Comment: quite the same, the offline option is pretty efficient, and calls PcapReader. It also supports filters directly, which is a cool feature

Answer (score 0):

I consider mixing multiprocessing and Django tricky. I was working on such solution once and finally I decided to use Celery and RabbitMQ.

Using Celery you can easily define task of processing single pcap. Then you can start a few independent workers for processing files in the background. Such solution will result in a little more complicated architecture (you need to provide message queue e. g. RabbitMQ and the Celery workers), however you can gain a much simpler code.

http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/django/first-steps-with-django.html

In my case Celery saved a lot of time.

You can also check this question and answers:

[How to use python multiprocessing module in django view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35699707/how-to-use-python-multiprocessing-module-in-django-view)