# how to do multiprocessing in django from the inside of views.py?

Tags: django, django-views, multiprocessing

I am trying to employ parallel processing in my `Django` web app. I am writing the multiprocessing code inside of the `views.py`, now I know i cannot write if **name** == **main** inside `django`. I did some research and got to know that, you can follow the below structure to go about incorporating multiprocessing inside `views.py`:

`def my_func(args):
    ....code here....`

`def optimize(request):
    for i in range(0,process_list):
        p = process(target = my_func,args=(arg_list))
        pros.append(p) 
        p.start()
    for t in pros:
        t.join()`

When I try the above code, i get an error at the line p.start() where it says errno32 broken pipe error. So how do I go about fixing it? Or is there any other module that i can use for multiprocessing?

Comment: You probably shouldn't be using `multiprocessing` in a view. A common approach is to use [celery](http://www.celeryproject.org/) to handle tasks in the background.

Comment: When I was doing my research, I came across this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35699707/how-to-use-python-multiprocessing-module-in-django-view, Here the community recommends him the procedure I have been trying.